# How to avoid restarting a long running and slow starting python program when executed from a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, session

I use Whisper to transcribe sound files. On my hardware it takes several minutes, if not dozens of minutes just to start it (it needs to load and process several GBs of data every time it is launched). I have wrapped this in a shell script that basically just feeds whisper with files in a for-loop.

The problem is that Whisper restarts and needs to reload all its data in every loop. It would be much faster to keep the Whisper "session" and just feed a new file in it when previous is finished. Can this be done in a shell script/for-loop "environment"?

There are two issues to consider:

1. The setup: I have three machines working on this, processing files in a network directory, and new files are added to this directory continuously.
2. To sync the machines, the first thing I do in the for-loop is to check if the input file has a corresponding outputfile. If not, I `touch` such an output file (e.g., the input file is "2023-Oct-25 15:25:12.aac", then I create corresponding text file using touch "2023-Oct-25 15:25:12.txt").

This prevents me from, when I start the script, to concatenate just a long command line command (something like (pseudo code) `whisper 1.aac > 1.txt --model large --language English, 2.aac > 2.txt --model large --language French , 3.aac > 3.txt --model medium --language French`  (note that the arguments are different in the three examples) - the commas indicate new "entries". I don't expect this to work.) of the existing files, because that is not a static "list".

Besides, I want to process the files in size order so when one machine is done with a file, it should look in the source directory and take the largest, which might be a file that was added after the execution begun, and process. This requirement, like the fact that new files are added continuously, also prevents me from, when the execution begins, create a long, complete, text string with a complete command.

Comment: Can you show us the script? Also, can this whisper thing take multiple input files? If not, there is nothing you will be able to do by scripting except perhaps concatenating all files into one huge one, transcribing that and then trying to separate.

Comment: The most efficient way is probably to abandon the `whisper` CLI tool and instead write your own script in `python`, loading the model once and feeding it with your inputs.